# Is there a way to convert Text to an int?

Tags: type-conversion

The code that is giving me trouble  is converting my content in the Text(), to an int so that I could use some arithmetic.  I know how to convert a string to an int, but for some reason Hadoop needs to read items in a file as a TExt().  I can't find a method to do this conversion.  ANy ideas on how this could be done?

```
    package BaseballStats;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import mrtools.CountMap;
    import mrtools.NBest;

    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

    public class StatReducer extends MapReduceBase
    implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text[]> {

        private Text Hits = new Text(); 
        private Text AtBats = new Text();
        //private Text Year = new Text();   
        int totalAtBats = 0;
        int totalHits = 0;
        float average = 0;
        Text [] Pair = {AtBats, Hits};

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                        OutputCollector<Text, Text[]> output,
                        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

            //Need to pull values from the Array and assign to AtBats    
            //THen total all at bats and hits per year (key)

            //Divide hits by at Bats to get batting average
            //Output batting average per year

            for (Text s: Pair) {           
                //Do your stuff here

                Pair[0] = AtBats;
                Pair[1] = Hits;
            }
            //Get values to key to sum up and get a total per year.
            while (values.hasNext()){
                int AB = Integer.parseInt(AtBats);
                int i = Integer.valueOf(AtBats);

                totalAtBats = AB + totalAtBats;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first convert the `Text` to a string using the `.toString()` method and then convert the result to an `int`.

Comment: Now in order to pass it to the collect object it neeeds to go back as a TEXT.  Is there a reverse method to do this easily?

Comment: Looks like you can just use the constructor `new Text(s)` where `s` is a string.

Comment: wait I could just convert to a string and then set atBats back to the total now.  NEvermind I got it.

Comment: One minor issue I am getting an error where it sees my totalAb and totalH is a string and not a Text

         / /need to create an array to match output
           //need to convert to a TExt again.
           String totalAB = Integer.toString(totalAtBats);
           new Text(totalAB);
           String totalH = Integer.toString(totalHits);
           new Text(totalH);
           Text[] Totals = {totalAB, totalH};